# Corda ownable state participant property

Tags: corda

I have read [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450545/back-tracking-ownablestate-in-corda).

As per this post, OwnableState participant's node will persist transactin copy but not state copy.

As per corda documentation OwnableState is a contract state that can have a single owner. OwnableState have participant properties. I have added Buyer and Seller as participant in OwnableState but state is only stored in Owners vault only not participant. However in LinearState state is persisted on both participants vault.

I need to understand diffrence between LinearState participant and OwnableState participant in corda.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic a node's vault uses to decide whether the node should store the state:

```
internal fun isRelevant(state: ContractState, myKeys: Set<PublicKey>): Boolean {
    val keysToCheck = when (state) {
        is OwnableState -> listOf(state.owner.owningKey)
        else -> state.participants.map { it.owningKey }
    }
    return keysToCheck.any { it in myKeys }
}
```

In words:

- For an `OwnableState`, the node will store the state if `OwnableState.owner` corresponds to one of the node's keys
- For `ContractState` and any other `ContractState` subclass, the node will store the state if `ContractState.participants` contains one of the node's keys